# using REST output into webpage

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, rest

i am very new to this and start with a template of start bootstrap.

And i got the code like on the webpage

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="morris-area-chart"></div>
                        </div>
```

This is backed by a js file named mores-data.js with contents like:

```
$(function() {

    Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart',
        data: [{
            period: '2010 Q1',
            iphone: 2666,
            ipad: null,
            itouch: 2647
        },  {
            period: '2010 Q4',
            iphone: 3767,
            ipad: 3597,
            itouch: 5689
        }, {
            period: '2011 Q4',
            iphone: 15073,
            ipad: 5967,
            itouch: 5175
        }, {
            period: '2012 Q2',
            iphone: 8432,
            ipad: 5713,
            itouch: 1791
        }],
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],
        labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],
        pointSize: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });

});
```

I have a rest service http://myserver/rest/charts

which returns response 
in the json format.

The problem I am stuck being a first timer is how to replace the sample date with the output of my REST service.

Any working code or pointers to it would greatly help.

Comment: When you post or get to your REST-service. Try writing debugger on your success. Like this:

`success: function(data) { debugger; }`

Now run your code with the console open and you'll be able to write data, to see what you get from the service.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json response from the REST service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used something like below

```
fdata=$.ajax({ url: 'http://myrestserver/rest/v1/feedbackerrors?onlyData=true',             
             type: 'get',  
             dataType: 'json',    
             success: function(output) {     console.log(output) ;    

                            }        
           });
```